# multiple conditional formatting

Tags: list, json-formatting

New to the whole JSON code within SharePoint lists, hit a brick wall and having no luck with research.

I require 2 conditional formatting writing into the cod but am not having much look.

First - if the 'Re-Certification Date'(which is a calculated column) is
Over 1035+ days = Green
1035 days = Orange
0 Days = Red

To do so I have the below JSON Code wrote:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,0), 'red', if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,60), 'orange', if(@currentField > addDays([$Certificationdate],1095), 'green','green',)",
    "color": "=if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,0), 'white', 'white')",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  }
}
```

Is this correct and the simplest way of writing it?

Question 2 - How do i add a second conditional formatting JSON code to the same column so that if the 'Status' column = 'Left the Company' the cell is filled black with black text?? i have tried a few ways and had no success.

Or is it possible to remove the date from the calculated column based on anothers status??

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a second condition to the `background-color` and `color` properties to check if the "Status" column equals "Left the Company". Here is the code snippet:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Status] == 'Left the Company', 'black', if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,0), 'red', if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,1035), 'orange', if(@currentField > addDays([$Certificationdate],1035), 'green','green')))",
    "color": "=if([$Status] == 'Left the Company', 'black', if(@currentField <= addDays(@now,0), 'white', 'white'))",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  }
}
```

Comment: Life saver, thank you very much!

Comment: @JB94 Im happy this worked for you, please mark it as the solution so that others may find it easier.